# Java printing fails on Linux if image is scaled down

Tags: java, image, printing, graphics

I want to print an image with PrinterJob, but it fails when the image is scaled down more than one sixth.

There is no exception, but the page is not printed. If I use PDF printer, the result file is empty.

- System: Linux 14.04 LTS
- Java version: 1.8.0_05
- Printer: Brother
  HLL2300D, Ubuntu PDF printer

You can test it with this code. If `divisor > 6`, the printing fails. The size of the original image is 2752x935 pixels.

```
public class PrinterTest implements Printable {

    @Override
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page)
            throws PrinterException {
        if (page > 0) {
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://munkalapszoftver.hu/images/logo.jpg");
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
            if (image != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
                int divisor = 7;
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth() / divisor, image.getHeight() / divisor, null);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            // Error handling
        }
        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        job.setPrintable(new PrinterTest());
        boolean doPrint = job.printDialog();
        if (doPrint) {
            try {
                job.print();
            } catch (PrinterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // Error handling
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea, why does it fail?

Comment: I've tested the code and it works fine. I've tried `divisor = 7, 8, 20, ...` and the image gets resized accordingly. Do you maybe have the image / PDF open in another application? Or are you behind a proxy / firewall, that filters out the picture?

Comment: @hamena314  thanks for your answer. The image is correctly loaded. The result depends only from the divisor. Maybe this failure occurs only on Linux system with a specific JRE version. I'm using Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS, the Java version is 1.8.0_05.

Comment: My test was with a Windows 7 machine with Java 1.8.0_65. So maybe it's an issue with the PDF printing itself? What program are you using to create the PDF?

Comment: I have tested with a Brother HLL2300D printer and with the default PDF printer of Ubuntu. I got the same result. Anyway I have fixed it: any time the image is too large, I downscale it before printing.

Comment: well you got BigInteger.... can't that do it for you??